# Data set for regression: different response values for same combination of input variables

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

Hey dear stackoverflowers,

I would like to perform (multiple) regression analysis on a large customer data set, trying to predict amount spent after initial purchase based on various independent variables, observed during the first purchase. 
In this data set, for the same combination of input variable values (say gender=male, age=30, income=40k, first_purchase_value = 99,90), I can have multiple observartions with varying y values (i.e. multiple customers share the same independent variable attributes, but behave differently according to their observed y values).

Is this a problem for regression analysis, i.e. do I have to condense these observations by e.g. averaging? I am getting negative R2 values, that's why I'm asking (I know that a linear model might also just be the wrong assumption here) ...

Thank you for helping me. I tried using the search function, but was unable to find similar topics (probably because the question is silly?).

Cheers!

Edit: This is the code I'm using:

```
spl <- sample.split(data$spent, SplitRatio = 0.75)
data_train <- subset(data, spl == TRUE)
data_test <- subset(data, spl == FALSE)
model_lm_spent <- lm(spent ~ ., data = data_train)
summary(model_lm_spent)
model_lm_predictions_spent <- predict(model_lm_spent, newdata = data_test) 
SSE_spent = sum((data_test$spent - model_lm_predictions_spent)^2)
SST_spent = sum((data_test$spent - mean(data$spent))^2)
1 - SSE_spent/SST_spent
```

Comment: smells like a situation where you might want to use a [mixed-effects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf)/hierarchical model (esp. if you just have samples from the different income tiers). if you poke around and decide that that makes sense, then you'll want to use [`lme4::lmer()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-15/topics/lmer)

Comment: No, that is not a problem, it is very common. However, negative R^2 values are impossible. (In fact, anything that is squared is positive, not just R.) Instead of assuming your problem is data, show the code you are using the build the model and get the R^2 and we can help you find the real problem.

Comment: @Gregor: I edited my initial post and included my code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @lefft thank you for your comment, I suspected something like that! However, I am not interested in creating sub-groups within my data set (unless you consider each customer a seperate group?). Would you say that my data is panel data, and as such should be analyzed using a fixed or random effect model?

Comment: Managed to achieve positive (albeit super small) R2 of 0.05 by 1.) removing outliers, 2.) ensuring independent variable is >0 (i.e. making sure I only analyze those customers that do purchase again), and 3.) transforming the independent variable "spent" with log(., base=exp(1)) ... Not too sure whether I'm happy with these manipulations though.